# Why is there an incorrect display of objects in the Pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a game on Pygame and faced with the problem that the objects are displayed incorrectly
I want the objects in a row but I wrote it diagonally

My game:

```
import pygame, controls
from gun import Gun
from pygame.sprite import Group

def run():

    pygame.init()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((700, 600))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Game1')
    bg_color = (0, 0, 0)
    gun = Gun(screen)
    bullets = Group()
    inos = Group()
    controls.create_army(screen, inos)

    while True:
        controls.events(screen, gun, bullets)
        gun.update_gun()
        controls.update(bg_color, screen, gun, inos, bullets)
        controls.update_bullets(bullets)
        controls.update_inos(inos)
run()
```

controls:

```
import pygame
import sys
from bullet import Bullet
from ino import Ino

def events(screen, gun, bullets):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                gun.mright = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                gun.mleft = True
            elif event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
                new_bullet = Bullet(screen, gun)
                bullets.add(new_bullet)

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d:
                gun.mright = False
            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                gun.mleft = False

def update(bg_color, screen, gun, inos, bullets):
    screen.fill(bg_color)
    for bullet in bullets.sprites():
        bullet.draw_bullet()
    gun.output()
    inos.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()

def update_bullets(bullets):
    bullets.update()
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 0:
            bullets.remove(bullet) 

def update_inos(inos):
    inos.update()


def create_army(screen, inos):
    ino = Ino(screen)
    ino_width = ino.rect.width
    number_ino_x = int((700 - 2 * ino_width) / ino_width)
    ino_height = ino.rect.height
    number_ino_y = int((800 - 100 - 2 * ino_height) / ino_height)

    for row_number in range(number_ino_y - 1):
        for ino_number in range(number_ino_x):
            ino = Ino(screen)
            ino.x = ino_width + (ino_width * ino_number)
            ino.y = ino_height + (ino_height * ino_number)
            ino.rect.x = ino.x
            ino.rect.y = ino.rect.height + (ino.rect.height * row_number)
            inos.add(ino)
```

soldiers:

```
import pygame 

class Ino(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, screen):
        super(Ino, self).__init__()
        self.screen = screen
        self.image = pygame.image.load(r'C:\Users\ralph\Downloads\Python\Game\Image\r.soldier.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = self.rect.width
        self.rect.y = self.rect.height
        self.x = float(self.rect.x)
        self.y = float(self.rect.y)

    def draw(self):
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)

    def update(self):
        self.y += 0.05
        self.rect.y = self.y
```

I got this result
But I need another

[image]

How can I fix this?
In my humble opinion the problem is in "controls" or "soldiers" update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The images are diagonal because you calculate the y-coordinate depending on the `ino_number`, so that the y-coordinate increases with increasing `ino_number`. The y-coordinate must be the same for all objects. Only the coordinated x must increase with the number `ino_number`:

```py
def create_army(screen, inos):
    # [...]

    for row_number in range(number_ino_y - 1):
        for ino_number in range(number_ino_x):
            ino = Ino(screen)
            ino.x = ino_width + (ino_width * ino_number)
            ino.y = ino_height
            ino.rect.x = ino.x
            ino.rect.y = ino.y
            inos.add(ino)
```